# using php/curl to access a zip file provided by a web server

Tags: php, curl

I have a feeling that my issue is a problem with my basic understanding of some of the HTTP nuances, but I will ask it here as a curl and php question.

I use a web application that can be used to store files, and if I use a browser to access a particular URI on the site, the browser will prompt me to store that file somewhere.  Note that the URI is asp code that sends back the file (somehow), not a simple file path on the web server.  Also, there appears to be a number of redirects that happen, but I am not sure if that is relevant because I have set the FOLLOWLOCATION option.

I am attempting to do that same thing using php and curl.  My PHP code looks like:

```php
$curlObj = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curlObj,  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curlObj,  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$tempFile = tempnam("","aes"); # create a temp file
$tempFH = fopen($tempFile,"w");
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_FILE, $tempFH);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
curl_exec($curlObj);
print_r(curl_getinfo($curlObj));
curl_close($curlObj);
```

When I look at the contents of the temp file, it's always the equivalent of the html data that is visible in my browser when I go that site, but not the file the browser allows me to save.  If I look at the htt header data and body, there is no reference to the file or its contents, so I am not sure how I would access it like the browser does.

Comment: Is $url actually the URL of the ZIP file? Is there a link (<`a href="https://...">`) or redirect (`<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://...">`) that points somewhere else?

Comment: No, the URL would be something like: "http:/myserver.com/DownloadFile.aspx?fiid=22&fid=45" , and that asp file (after redirects) puts some html in my browser, but also causes my browser to save the contents of the zip file.

Comment: sometimes it helps to add an useragent
$userAgent = ‘Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)’;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);

Comment: Turns out that the returned page has a hidden form and javascript that is triggered onload which does the work to retrieve the file.  I need to somehow execute the javascript in my php code, or else try to parse it to locate the actual file.  Thanks for the assistance.